# Could not find a declaration file for module 'alertifyjs'. implicitly has an 'any' type

Tags: angular, installation, version-control, package, alertifyjs

I have installed
`npm install alertifyjs`
and i am using angullar version 16 and alertify version `"alertifyjs": "^1.13.1",`

After install all required modules still getting error like

> Could not find a declaration file for module 'alertifyjs'.
> 'c:/Users/lenovo/OneDrive/Desktop/Angular/kanha-app/node_modules/alertifyjs/build/alertify.js'
> implicitly has an 'any' type.   Try `npm i --save-dev @types/alertifyjs` if it exists or add a new declaration (.d.ts) file
> containing `declare module 'alertifyjs';`ts(7016)

I have give the correct path in angular.json as well still getting error,

these is my alertify component

```
> import { Injectable } from '@angular/core'; import * as alertify from
> 'alertifyjs'; @Injectable({   providedIn: 'root' }) export class
> AlertService {   constructor() { }   Confirm(message: string,
> okCallback: () => any) {
>     alertify.confirm(message, (e: any) => {
>       if (e) {
>         okCallback();
>       }
>       else { }
>     }).setHeader('Smart-DPU');   }   Alert(alertTitle: string, message: string) {
>     alertify.alert(alertTitle, message).set('modal', true);   }   Success(message: string) {
>     alertify.success(message);   }   Error(message: string) {
>     alertify.error(message);   }   Warning(message: string) {
>     alertify.warning(message);   }   Message(message: string) {
>     alertify.message(message);   } }
```

note- I am new i angular , please explain the solution in details please,
thanks in advance.